# `rspec` with `spring` doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spring, rspec

I wanted to use `spring` instead of `spork`.

I installed `spring` and `spring-commands-rspec`, and after installing I created binstubs by `bundle exec spring binstub --all`.

When I run `bin/rspec`, I get only this result.

```
No examples found.


Finished in 0.00099 seconds
```

`bin/rake routes` gives me proper result. And `bundle exec rspec` tests all example I have like this.

```
Finished in 6.63 seconds
20 examples, 2 failures, 11 pending

Failed examples:
```

What am I missing? Where should I configure the place of test directories?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try specifiying the directory:

```
$ bin/rspec spec/
```

Comment: Great, it works now! I don't understand why I must specify the directory, though.